# Can I restrict who can create a new page in a SharePoint Wiki?

Tags: permissions, wiki

I have a SharePoint Wiki setup as a subsite under my main sharepoint site but I want to allow everyone to add content to pages but only give certain people the ability to create new Wiki pages.  I'm concerned that if I let everyone just create pages the site will become very jumbled and messy.

Thank you for any help or direction you can provide.

Comment: When you enable the publishing infrastructure, than you can create a approval before the wiki age is published. Maybe this will be a good solution too?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom permission level that did not give users add rights. They would simply have edit rights. This would allow them to curate content, but not be allowed to add new wiki pages. Only those with the default contribute address would be able to add new pages.

Outdated screenshots, but the process is the same, http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1019.